# Increase a cell by the same amount another cell is increased by

Tags: microsoft-excel

If for explample - I have £9.50 in cell A1 and £6.50 in cell A2.

If i manually increase cell A2 by £0.50, making it £7.00 then i need cell A1 to automatically increase by 0.50 too.

Can this be done by formula and if so what is the formula?

Comment: Is the increase by £0.50 entered by hand, i.e. you are manually typing a new figure into that cell, or is it being increased as the result of a formula acting on that cell?

Answer (score 2):

No, this cannot be done with a formula. I don't even think it can be done with VBA, because as soon as you overwrite the 6.50 with the 7.00, there is no reference to what the cell value was before the change, hence no way of working out that the difference between before and after is 0.50. To do that you would have to keep a history of the cell values somewhere, which is a mighty complicated project.

You may want to re-do your approach.

Have the two values in A1 and A2. In B1 enter 0.5

In C1 enter `=A1+$B$1`

Copy down to C2

The value you enter into B1 will be added to both A1 and A2 and the respective results will show in C1 and C2.

Comment: I think you might be able to do the trick by using the workbook_selectionchanged event in a macro (remember the current value and once it was changed act accordingly). But i would recommend redoing your approach as Teylyn suggested. It should result in the better solution.

Comment: @TheUser1024, I think you mean the Worksheet_change event. But that will only fire AFTER the cell has been changed and it will not be able to reference to the value the cell had before the change. There is also the Worksheet_SelectionChange event which could be used to copy the selected cell's value to a temporary variable, but what if the user does not change the selection, just sits on A1 and keeps entering numbers? As I said above, retaining a history of previous cell entries is a bit more complex.